# Error inflating class... (CardView)

Tags: java, android, xml, view, android-view

When I start my app the error

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.tobi.zoom_gallery.SquareCardView

is shown.

I want to show 3 columns of 40 x 40px images in a RecyclerView with GridLayout.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RV);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(getResources());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

MyAdapter (for RecyclerView):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder>{

    ArrayList<String> names;
    Resources resources;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> names, Resources resources) {
        this.names = names;
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_view_xml, parent, false);

        return new MyHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.drawable));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 50;
    }
  }
```

MyHolder (the ViewHolder for a CardView):

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    public MyHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    }
}
```

SquareCardView (i use i a modified CardView to make it square; you'll se in the XML-file)

```
public class SquareCardView extends android.support.v7.widget.CardView{

    public SquareCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int    heightMeasureSpec)        
{
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = width > height ? height : width;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```

The XMl-file (here i use the SquareCardView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.user.s.SquareCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</com.example.user.s.SquareCardView>
```

And i get this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.tobi.zoom_gallery.SquareCardView
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                   at com.example.tobi.zoom_gallery.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:30)
                                                                                   at com.example.tobi.zoom_gallery.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:15)
```

**MyAdapter.java:30** is this piece of code in **MyAdapter**

```
View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_view_xml, parent, false);
```

.

**Please tell me why the Cardview can't be inflaten.**

Answer (score 2):

to use `SquareView` in your `xml` you have to override the constructor that takes `(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` which is the one used when the view  is inflated from the xml. E.g.

```
  public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
  }
```

Comment: I don' understand exactly...What am i supposed to do now?

Comment: add that constructor in your `SquareCardView`

Comment: Thanks, I addes that constructor... But now i don't know why, there isn't shown any image... When i start th app i get a white screen.

Comment: it is difficult to say what's wrong if you don't post the code you are actually using. E.g. your MyAdapter has no constructor that takes only a Resource object.

Comment: That is the code im actually using. I just changed the constructor of the SquareCardView.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for Square view you need to include the parameter AttributeSet attr to be able to use it in xml.

From android dev:

```
    class PieChart extends View {
    public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        }
    }
```